# Restore deleted application classes and their peoplecode in peoplesoft

Tags: peoplesoft

Some of my application classes got deleted. So is there any way to restore them to database? I need peoplecode of those classes.
Thanks,
Shyam

Answer (score 1):

---

If you have access to a database that contains the application classes, then you can add them to an Application Designer project and migrate them across.

If these are delivered Application Classes, you might be able to import them using the PeopleTools project (e.g. PPLTLS84CUR) found on your application server under .